raspberry pi OS desktop и GRUB. Подскажите плз, в чем дело
На пустой SSD накатываю raspberry pi OS. После попытки запуска попадаю в консоль GRUB. Подскажите, в чем дело и как решить вопросик.

Возможно, поврежден загрузчик GRUB. Проверь наличие и исправность раздела EFI:
В нем должен быть сам GRUB и файлы системы с дровами.
Также, он должен использовать fat32

скорее всего вы правы. я решил, пока не установлена система, заменить SSD на больший по объему и с новым дмском всё зааботало как надо.
